# rsconnect to shinyapps.io returns "namespace ‘sass’ 0.3.1 is being loaded, but >= 0.4.0 is required"

Tags: r, shinyapps

I am trying to upload a shiny app onto shinyapps.io using

```
rsconnect::deployApp('superb/inst/myshiny')
```

I am using R 4.0.3 (either Rterm or Rgui), I updated all the packages. In the process, deployApp tries to install gWidgets2tcltk which fails (my guess is that I am not in RStudio). In shinyapps.io logs, I get this error message:

```
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : 
   namespace ‘sass’ 0.3.1 is being loaded, but >= 0.4.0 is required
Calls: local ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

This requirement is not in my application. Is there a solution to solve this?

Comment: Try to update the package is.. `update.packages('sass')` The current R version R 4.1.0. So, it may be better to update to that version and then reinstall thosepackages

Comment: As said, I updated ALL the packages on my computer. However, the error is on the server "shinyapps.io", not on my computer. Can I ask them to update?

Comment: it must be then the server package update